# Plasmashell crashes randomly

Tags: kubuntu, crash, plasma-5

Whatever I am working on, high or low intensity, every now and then my plasmashell will freeze.

The icons on the bottom panel will not change, but applications will open and close. Therefore clicking on the icon for one application will often open a separate unrelated application.

I can fix the issue with  `killall plasmashell`  and  `kstart plasmashell`  but it doesn't seem like a reasonable approach.

I am not sure where to start to diagnose and solve, but also I cannot find anyone else describing the same issue online.

Running Kubuntu 18.04.1  on Ryzen 5 1600 with Nvidia 1060

Looking for some advice on how to start troubleshooting.

Comment: additional point to note is that if I have manually restarted plasmashell, it doesnt seem to crash at all. Also I am using Nvidia driver version 390.48

Comment: I just reinstalled kubuntu from the 18.04.1 release. I still get this issue. In addition it now happens at boot where the launcher will show up but nothing on the desktop or indeed the desktop image shows up. Again resetting plasmashell temporarily fixes this issue. What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?